# Compare date with if statement in jQuery to do list

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, if-statement, compare

I want to highlight overdue task when refresh page and when click on add task button such as the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add-task').on('click',function(){
    $('.task-date').each(function(){
      var a = new Date().dateFormat('dd/mm/yy').getTime();
      var b = formatDate(b,'dd/mm/yy').getTime();
      var task = new Date($('.task-date')).getTime();
      if(task < b) {
        return $('todo-task').addClass('overdue');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I tried some other ways but still not working so please check JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ndh2311/3z0yocer/7/) and source site [here](http://sdaityari.github.io/to-do-list/) and help me. Thank you.

Comment: I think you should be using `this` here instead of `var task = new Date($('.task-date')).getTime();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var d = new Date();
    var date = d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth()+1 + "/" + d.getFullYear();
    var overDueClass= "";
    // Add Task
    var generateElement = function(params){
    var parent = $(codes[params.code]),
        wrapper;

    if (!parent) {
        return;
    }
    //  Check the current date is less than to-do date.
    if(params.date < date) {
    overDueClass= "overdue";
  } else {
    overDueClass="";
  };

    wrapper = $("<div />", {
        "class" : defaults.todoTask+" "+overDueClass,
        "id" : defaults.taskId + params.id,
        "data" : params.id
    }).appendTo(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var generateElement = function(params){
        var parent = $(codes[params.code]),
            wrapper;

        if (!parent) {
            return;
        }
        var curDate=new Date();
        var overDueClass="";
        if(params.date<curDate){ //  Check the current date is less than to-do date here
           overDueClass=" overdue";
        }
        wrapper = $("<div />", {
            "class" : defaults.todoTask+overDueClass,
            "id" : defaults.taskId + params.id,
            "data" : params.id
        }).appendTo(parent);
      .....................
      ...............
}
```

For solve your task no need to create new functions. You may just apply the logic in `generateElement` function in your `todo.js` file.

Comment: Thank you, i tried some other way base on your answer but it still not working.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sumesh TG, this is source code on github: https://github.com/ndh2311/to-do-list.git

Comment: Hey, thanks you @Sumesh TG, base on your answer i finished it.

Comment: @NguyễnĐìnhHảiFX00606 ok